# How to add contents of char[] array to new char[] letters? - java

Tags: java

I try to implement hasNext() method in my iterator.

```
public boolean hasNext() {
       filename = this.fileContent.getFileName();
       int charLineSize = 0;
       Scanner in = null;
       ArrayList<Character> charList = new ArrayList<>

       try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath)))) {

           while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
               String line = scanner.nextLine();
               charLineSize = line.split("\\s+").length;
               String wordsline = line.split("\\s+").toLowerCase();
               charList.addAll(new ArrayList<>(wordsline.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList())));
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        if (index < charLineSize) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
   }

    public String next() {
       if (hasNext()) {
           return charList.get(index++);
       } else {
           return null;
       }
    }
```

First of all, I split line into chars here. Is it correct way to store all chars in charList and update it after scanner goes through each line?

I want to get specific char in Next() method.

Comment: why don't you  directly split the lines to the char and put them in the char[]array by using .toCharArray()?

Answer (score 0):

> How to split them into chars?

Use [`line.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray())

> Second, when I do so, how to add the content of letters to char[] array after each line?

You *can't*. Once an array has been created, you cannot cannot change its size. This implies you need to know the total amount of characters beforehand, which is probably not the case.

Declare `array` as a list of characters on which you can call `array.add(char)`.

```
List<Character> array = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Ok. But how to do that? How to declare array as list of character on which I will be able to add characters? The Point is that I need to store characters in a list and being able to add there new characters line by line. Then in Next() method I will have to be able to return character depending on index.

Comment: Thank you. How will I be able to get the specific character from that list by index?

Comment: @JeyKey On a list you can do `list.get(index)`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)

Answer (score 0):

To convert to char array, and add the content you can use the following methods:

1. Converting to char array:

   `line.toCharArray()`
2. Getting the list from char array:

   `ArrayList<Character> charList = new ArrayList<>(line.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList()));`
3. To add content:

   `charList.add(c);`

Comment: Thank you. But how to add this content after each line? Here I do it once during declaration of charList.

Comment: For this, you can use `charList.addAll(new ArrayList<>(line.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList())));`

Comment: But where exaclty? Please look at my code again. I updated it.
Should It be like this right now? Inside while loop at the end?:
charList.addAll(new ArrayList<>(words.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList())));

Comment: Instead of `char[] words = wordsline.toCharArray();
               charList(line.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList()));
               charList.add(c);`, use `charList.addAll(new ArrayList<>(wordsline.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList())));`

Comment: Thank you very much. I will update the code again. But is the Next() method correct?

Comment: It'll work. But what you are doing here is reading from the file for each `next`. That is too much IO for too little task. Try to initialize the `charlist` during class initialization or before calling `next`.

Comment: I know that. To use Collectors, do I have to import java.util.stream.Collectors or something?

Comment: Yes you have to import java.util.stream.Collectors.